# I want to use JQuery Datepicker on a template I used, but because of the integrated JQuery Core file from the template, I can't get it to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

UPDATE: I have removed the $.noConflict(); line from the code, and what happened is all the other JQuery files in the template didn't work, all of them except the custom JQuery Datepicker files I

I exclusively want the JQuery Datepicker + my custom codes to work in there, but I can't get it to work. Probably because of both JQuery files in one site. I have read about the noConflict function, but I think I can't get it to work properly.

Here is my code about the noConflict I used:

```
<!-- Datepicker Conflict Js -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "js/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <!-- Datepicker JavaScript function -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $.noConflict();
         $(function() {
            $("#checkInDate").datepicker({
                dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
                minDate: 0,
                onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                    var d = $.datepicker.parseDate(inst.settings.dateFormat, dateText);
                    d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
                    $("#checkOutDate").val($.datepicker.formatDate(inst.settings.dateFormat, d));

                },
            }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());


            $("#checkOutDate").datepicker({
                dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
                minDate: 0
            }).datepicker("setDate", +1);
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Is there any error in console? btw, `jquery-ui` does not conflict with `jquery`. Or you have jQuery being loaded in another place? If so, is there any reason you're loading again here?

Comment: Update: I have removed the $.noConflict(); line from the code, and what happened is all the other JQuery files in the template didn't work, all of them except the custom JQuery Datepicker files I have.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your install locations. Try using the source the docs, and see if that works.

https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/